# Can the Gotek floppy emulator be made to work with classic Macs?

Tags: hardware, emulation, apple-macintosh, floppy-disk

The Gotek floppy emulators are really popular in the retro scene. I have one modified (firmware update) to work with my Amiga 500.

Can one be made to work with any of the classic line of Macintosh computers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gotek floppy emulator appears to only support two firmwares: Cortex (Amiga only) and HcX (Amiga, Atari, Amstrad, and Spectrum).

There is another floppy emulator, the [BMOW Floppy Emu](http://www.bigmessowires.com/floppy-emu/), which supports classic Macintosh hardware (Macintosh, Apple II, and Lisa Floppy/Hard Disk).  There are firmware downloads on the linked page.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly... Six years since your post, things have moved on a little. Work seems to be underway on the [FlashFloppy firmware](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy) for the Gotek.

See [Apple II and/or classic Macintosh support #733](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy/issues/733) and this question, [Which wires need to be changed to use a Gotek floppy emulator on an Apple Mac?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/25946/202).