# Which wires need to be changed to use a Gotek floppy emulator on an Apple Mac?

Tags: apple-ii, apple-macintosh, floppy-drive

#### Preamble

I own a Gotek floppy emulator that I use with my BBC Model B. It is the latest model with the Artery AT32F435 MCU<sup>1</sup>, so there is a lot of memory space and processing power for future features in firmware updates. I am looking to minimise expense and trying to see if it is possible to use that same Gotek floppy emulator with a Macintosh, or Apple ][.

After looking on a couple of forums<sup>(2, 3)</sup> and then this question, [Can the Gotek floppy emulator be made to work with classic Macs?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1872/202), the answer seems to be:

*"No, because the cable/connector/interface/operation/electrical_signalling of a standard floppy interface is different from that employed by Apple"*.

I am well aware that:

- Mac floppy drives were very different (or superior, depending upon your own particular bias) to standard floppy drives (auto-ejecting being the first thing that springs to mind), and;
- Electrically, the ID34 connector for the standard floppy, and the ID20 connector, for the Apple floppy, are not wired up in the same way and obviously don't fit together.

#### Standard floppy interface working on an Apple IIc

However, this question, [What are the differences between the various HxC Floppy Emulator hardware options when used with an Apple II?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12792/202), links to a short video, [Slim HxC Floppy Emulator on Apple 2c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaR9noqb0JE), showing a standard floppy drive emulator being used on an Apple ][.

That video is produced by closed source commerical outfit *HxC*, and the hardware is **not** a Gotek. That seems to have been a side project and isn't commerically available, so that is a dead end.

#### Another example of it working with an Apple ][ system

This closed issue on Github, [Using Flashfloppy with Trackstar 128 (reading Apple 2 disks) #333](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy/issues/333) also shows that it can be (partially) done (using HxC firmware)<sup>4</sup>:

> I haven't had a lot of success so far; HXC firmware at least gets me far enough to boot an Apple II game but disks are read-only.

#### Joining the dots

Now seeing that:

- the [Floppy Emu](http://www.bigmessowires.com/floppy-emu/), referred to in [this answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1873/202) works with *both* a Mac and Apple ][ (as demonstrated in this video, [Floppy Emu disk emulator for vintage Apple II, Macintosh, and Lisa computers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8bcOGLNdzU) ) - implying that the wiring of the 19/20 pin interface of the Apple ][ and Macintosh, respectively, is compatible, and;
- the Gotek has an open source firmware now available, [FlashFloppy](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy)  - implying that it can be changed/modded

it doesn't take much of a stretch of imagination to realise that some firmware changes could be made (either via a Feature Request, or a private fork and a bit of hacking) to add *both* Apple ][ and Macintosh functionality to a Gotek - just leaving the electrical interface needing to be sorted out.

#### TL;DR

So, my question is, *ignoring for the moment the required firmware changes*, what cable changes are required to get a Gotek half-way talking to an Apple ][ or Mac?

That is to say:

- What are the custom changes to the floppy cable that were made in that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaR9noqb0JE), but not shown?
- What, if any, additional *discrete* logic is required (logic level shifting, glue logic, etc.)?

  - Clearly any discrete logic *could* be dispensed with by having the logic handled in firmware. However, this would probably require a Gotek to be reflashed each time it is moved between an Apple device and a PC-floppy drive compatible device. So an external small logic board would be preferrable.
  - Without trying to increase the scope of this question too much, I'm looking for an *outline* of this required logic.

*Note: This question is for **Apple ][** and **classic Macintosh** and a USB based solution will not work. Neither the Apple ][ nor Macintosh have USB, and the floppy was phased out for the modern Apple computers starting with the coloured 1999 iMac.*

---

#### References

<sup>1</sup> See Github: [keirf](https://github.com/keirf)/[Flashfloppy](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy) - [Wiki](https://github.com/keirf/FlashFloppy/wiki) - [Gotek Models](https://github.com/keirf/FlashFloppy/wiki/Gotek-Models)

<sup>2</sup> [GOTEK Floppy Emulators in Classic Macs?](https://68kmla.org/bb/index.php?threads/gotek-floppy-emulators-in-classic-macs.35046/)

<sup>3</sup> [Gotek floppy emulator?](https://www.reddit.com/r/VintageApple/comments/a6557y/gotek_floppy_emulator/)

<sup>4</sup> Photos of (and information about) the Trackstar can be found here, [AppleLogic - Trackstar](http://www.applelogic.org/Trackstar.html), and here, [Trackstar 128](https://www.diskman.com/presents/trackstar/ts128.htm).

#### Footnote

Here is the pinout of the Apple Floppy Drive Cable *821-0655* from [Oldcrap.org - Apple Disk 5.25](https://oldcrap.org/2018/08/24/apple-disk-5-25/)

[image: Apple Disk 5.25 connector]

And this would appear to be a standard floppy connector pinout

[image: Standard floppy connector pinout]

Comment: Commenting out of ignorance: why can it not be done through USB? (because you don't say which type of Mac)

Comment: Neither the Apple ][ nor Macintosh have USB, and the floppy was phased out for the modern Apple computers starting with the coloured 1999 iMac.

Comment: It’s definitely not just wires that need to be changed — e.g. on an Apple II the computer takes direct responsibility for the four phases of the stepper, whereas on a classic drive you just indicate direction and request a step. Also on the Mac drive speed varies by zone (automatically as of the 800kb drive).

Comment: First, make sure the Mac doesn't fling your USB stick into your face when ejecting a disk ;)

Comment: @Tommy - but that is for a physical drive, surely the Gotek can ignore those precise controls? Or, I guess that you mean some logic is required to convert the Apple signals to the equivalent Standard floppy signals, so that the Gotek knows where to look on the *virtual floppy image*, which on the USB stick - however the Gotek achieves this, of which I am really not sure... yet. FWIW, someone else seems to have also done it, see [Using Flashfloppy with Trackstar 128 (reading Apple 2 disks) #333](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy/issues/333). Unless it is the same person as in the video.

Comment: @Greenonline it would definitely need to accept those signals and process them appropriately, yes. So on that basis alone I think a custom cable plus a custom firmware would be required, even if it’d be very similar to what the Gotek already runs.

Comment: @Tommy Ah, so there are two options. (1) (My initial thought) Preserve the connection pins layout, & make some additional glue logic to convert the Apple signalling to that of the PC, or (2) (As you suggest) Change the cabling *and* the Gotek firmware related to the interface pins, so as to read the Apple signalling. Option 2 would then make the Gotek incompatible with a BBC, whereas option 1 wouldn't. I believe the firmware is in two distinct parts: the interface, &; the disk image format reading. I hoped to preserve the i/f fw as much as possible & use discrete ICs to convert the signals.

Comment: @Greenonline My concern would be whether the Apple II allows copy-protected software enough low-level control as to require the Apple signalling for successful reading of whatever on-disk format they use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a feature request shortly after posting the above question,  [Apple II and/or classic Macintosh support #733](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy/issues/733).

Today there has been some activity on the issue, most notably:

> Mainly it will be an issue of connecting signals correctly to the ID34. However, the head stepper is directly controlled by 4 phase lines PH0-3. So the main work is in connecting those to appropriate input lines on the Gotek, and using them to step between tracks (and half tracks? and quarter tracks?).
>
> Beyond that I reckon you could use HFE image files as a raw container for Apple GCR bitcells.
>
> ...
>
> Further, I think /WREQ and WR would connect to ID34 Write Gate and Write Data.
>
> RD would connect to ID34 Read Data.
>
> /DRVEN would connect to ID34 Select (pin 10, say)
>
> WRPROT would connect to ID34 Write Protect.
>
> PH0-3 would connect to remaining input pins: MOTOR, DIR, STEP, SIDE.
> And firmware would need to interpret phase signals on these pins.
>
> I'm not sure on "sense" of some Apple pins (eg is RD active high or
> active low) and on details like whether phase signals interact with
> drive select. Nor how/when Apple drive spins up since there's no MOTOR
> signal.
>
> Probably some work with a scope or logic analyser on a real Drive II
> will be needed at some points.

So, it is looking promising.

---

In addition, [this post](https://github.com/keirf/flashfloppy/issues/733#issuecomment-1368199700) on the issue has a link to some *very* interesting timing diagrams (which I can't really summarise suitably in this answer):

> This might be helpful:
> https://embeddedmicro.weebly.com/apple-2iie.html